# create a button for google sheets mobile app/ range not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile

I am trying to create a dropdown 'button' which will trigger my 'function main' in Google Sheets' mobile app, but the error says 'range cannot be found'. Could you please advise how the code should be adjusted? Can it be because the spreadsheet has multiple sheets and I need to define the sheet name? I tried this way but still not working. The error says range not found.

```js
function onEdit(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Թերթ9");
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear();
    }
  }
}


function main(e) {moveData(); autoSort();}

function moveData(e) 
{
  // 1. Retrieve values from the source and target sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1w5AtGaZbUWpmeWXv9S8anNXPvOw1xqbU_VEj3LRewMM");
  var [srcSheet, targetSheet] = ['Գնումներ', 'Թերթ9'].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  var [srcValues, targetValues] = [[srcSheet, "AB2:AF"], [targetSheet, "A3:E"]].map(s => s[0].getLastRow() == 1 ? [] : s[0].getRange(s[1] + s[0].getLastRow()).getValues());

  // 2. Create objects for searching values of the column "A".
  var [srcObj, targetObj] = [srcValues, targetValues].map(e => e.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {}));

  // 3. Check update values at the target sheet.
  var updatedValues = targetValues.map(([a, ...b]) => [a, ...(srcObj[a] || b)]);
  // 4. Check append values.
  var appendValues = srcValues.reduce((ar, [a, ...b]) => {
    if (!targetObj[a]) ar.push([a, ...b]);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 5. Update the target sheet.
  var values = [...updatedValues, ...appendValues];
  targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

function autoSort(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Թերթ9")
const range = ws.getRange(3,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,12)
range.sort({column: 3, descending: false})
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]: The code should be the minimal to reproduce the error, the error should be added textually, when the code reads / write data, add sample data, in the case th spreadsheets this should include the sheet name and the relevant references. Sometimes is good to add the column and row headers (A,B,C, ...1,2,3...), others it better to add A1 notation references.

Comment: If you are calling the onEdit(e) function from the script editor then that is why you getting the error because the object which populates the e comes from the event trigger which is not provide from call from the script editor or a menu.  There may be no problem at all if you just load in to script editor and save it and edit the sheet appropriately to trigger the action.

Answer (score 0):

The function works on mobile with this script.

```html
function createEditTrigger() {
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("main")
   .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
   .onEdit()
   .create();
}


function main(e) {moveData(); autoSort();}

function moveData(e) 
{
  // 1. Retrieve values from the source and target sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1w5AtGaZbUWpmeWXv9S8anNXPvOw1xqbU_VEj3LRewMM");
  var [srcSheet, targetSheet] = ['Պատվերներ', 'Գնումների ցանկ'].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  var [srcValues, targetValues] = [[srcSheet, "AB2:AF"], [targetSheet, "A2:E"]].map(s => s[0].getLastRow() == 1 ? [] : s[0].getRange(s[1] + s[0].getLastRow()).getValues());

  // 2. Create objects for searching values of the column "A".
  var [srcObj, targetObj] = [srcValues, targetValues].map(e => e.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => (o[a] = b, o), {}));

  // 3. Check update values at the target sheet.
  var updatedValues = targetValues.map(([a, ...b]) => [a, ...(srcObj[a] || b)]);
  // 4. Check append values.
  var appendValues = srcValues.reduce((ar, [a, ...b]) => {
    if (!targetObj[a]) ar.push([a, ...b]);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 5. Update the target sheet.
  var values = [...updatedValues, ...appendValues];
  targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

function autoSort(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Գնումների ցանկ")
const range = ws.getRange(3,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,12)
range.sort({column: 3, descending: false});
}
```

I just need to further define it so that the function will work only if Cell A is edited (for example if a checkbox value True). Could you please have a look how the code could be adjusted for working the script only if cel A is edited?
Thanks in advance!